# How to access the body after a get request() in nodeJs

Tags: json, node.js, http, parsing, get

I have tried to use JSON.parse and request.on modules but none of the examples I have seen has helped me much.  Can you send me an example of accessing "body" to create an array (parsing to JSON)?  I'm a newbie in nodeJs.

Thank you in advance!

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
                url: 'URL with credentials and filter',
};


request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error); 

    console.log(body);

});
```

Comment: If the response you received was indeed json, JSON.parse(body) would do what you want. So, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to convert the json file in a csv file.  Do I have to create an empty array and then use JSON.parse(body) to move it to the array?  And yes it is a Json response.

Comment: No , JSON.parse takes a string and will give you the json object, so you just need to do var result = JSON.parse (body) and your result will be the json array, assuming the body is a json array

Comment: It worked... why documentation is so arid for a simple statement like that.  Thank you very much!